How to retrieve dictionary key when knowing value on one of its attributes?
Recently I was working on my Netbox automation using Ansible. I prepared task, which collects information about network interfaces that looks like below:
"interface_ips": {
  "br0": {
    "ipv4": [                
      "10.0.0.10",
      "10.0.0.11"
    ],
    "ipv6": [],
    "mac": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
    "mtu": "1500",
    "type": "bridge"
  },
  "lxcbr0": {
    "ipv4": [
      "10.100.0.10"
    ],
    "ipv6": [],
    "mac": "ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa",
    "mtu": "1500",
    "type": "bridge"
  }
}

I wanted to iterate over collected IPs (IPv4 + IPv6) and return interface name for corresponding IP.
The output I want is the following:

10.0.0.10 - br0 - host
10.0.0.11 - br0 - host
10.100.0.10 - lxcbr0 - host

Some interfaces might have multiple IPs assigned, so it's very important to iterate over every IP.
I managed to do following task, but it doesn't iterate over every address, only first ipv4 address.
- name: Extract IPv4 addresses and interface names
  set_fact:
    ip_interface_map: "{{ ip_interface_map | default({}) | combine({item.value.ipv4[0]: item.key}) }}"
    loop: "{{ interface_ips | dict2items }}"

Can this be done easily somehow?

Could you specify what output do you want to get?

Update your question to show exactly the behavior you want. You're asking for a hostname, but the data you show in your question doesn't include any hostnames.

@AlexanderPletnev I've updated question with more details and wanted output.

Given an ip address, you want to find the name of the interface to which it was assigned. To do that, we need to build a data structure that maps addresses to interface names. I like to use filters for this sort of thing, since that allows us to implement the logic in Python.
If we drop the following into filter_plugins/filters.py:
def build_address_map(interface_ips):
    address_map = {}
    for iface, config in interface_ips.items():
        for addr in config["ipv4"]:
            address_map[addr] = iface
        for addr in config["ipv6"]:
            address_map[addr] = iface

    return address_map


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "build_address_map": build_address_map,
        }

Then we can write something like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    collected_ips:
    - 10.0.0.10
    - 192.168.10.100
    - 10.100.0.10

    interface_ips: {
        "br0": {
            "ipv4": [
                "10.0.0.10","10.0.0.11"
            ],
            "ipv6": [],
            "mac": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
            "mtu": "1500",
            "type": "bridge"
        },
        "lxcbr0": {
            "ipv4": [
                "10.100.0.10"
            ],
            "ipv6": [],
            "mac": "ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa",
            "mtu": "1500",
            "type": "bridge"
        }
      }
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        address_map: "{{ interface_ips | build_address_map }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "address {{ item }} is assigned to {{ address_map[item]|default('unknown')}}"
      loop: "{{ collected_ips }}"

Which produces as output:
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.0.0.10) => {
    "msg": "address 10.0.0.10 is assigned to br0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=192.168.10.100) => {
    "msg": "address 192.168.10.100 is assigned to unknown"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.100.0.10) => {
    "msg": "address 10.100.0.10 is assigned to lxcbr0"
}


As far as in understand, the op wants both ip addresses for the first interface? You only return the one in your collected ips list

The question says, "I wanted to iterate over collected IPs (IPv4 + IPv6) and return interface name for corresponding IP.". This answer does that: it iterates over collected_ips and returns the interface associated with each one, assuming that such a mapping exists.

It also explicitly states `The output I want is the following:
10.0.0.10 - br0 - host
10.0.0.11 - br0 - host
10.100.0.10 - lxcbr0 - host`

As I mentioned in my comment on the question, the op hasn't provided any sample data containing hostnames, so it's not possible to produce that output without making significant assumptions about the organization of the data. Otherwise, this produces the correct data; presumably in actual use collected_ips would be completed populated; I just put samples in it to demonstrate how this would work for ips that can be mapped and for ones that cannot be mapped.

@larsks In main post there's sample for only one host and structure interface_ips is created for every host in my inventory. Basically i have a lot of hosts with multiple network interfaces and some of them have bound multiple IPs (primary + floating ip). Thank You for Your input.

It seems that it works as intended. Thank you!

@MateuszJasek if this answer resolved your issue, please consider marking it "accepted" by checking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks!


Convert the dictionary to a list
  interface_ips | dict2items:
    - key: br0
      value:
        ipv4: [10.0.0.10, 10.0.0.11]
        ipv6: []
        mac: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
        mtu: '1500'
        type: bridge
    - key: lxcbr0
      value:
        ipv4: [10.100.0.10]
        ipv6: []
        mac: ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa
        mtu: '1500'
        type: bridge




Iterate subelements

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.1 }} - {{ item.0.key }}"
    loop: "{{ interface_ips | dict2items | subelements('value.ipv4') }}"

gives (abridged)
  msg: 10.0.0.10 - br0
  msg: 10.0.0.11 - br0
  msg: 10.100.0.10 - lxcbr0

The same loop with subelements('value.ipv6') will be skipped because all ipv6 lists are empty
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.1 }} - {{ item.0.key }}"
    loop: "{{ interface_ips | dict2items | subelements('value.ipv6') }}"


Optionally, create a dictionary first

  ip_interface_map: "{{ dict(interface_ips | dict2items | 
                             json_query('[].[key, 
                                            [value.ipv4, value.ipv6]|[]]')) }}"

gives
  ip_interface_map:
    br0:
    - 10.0.0.10
    - 10.0.0.11
    lxcbr0:
    - 10.100.0.10


Iterate subelements

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.1 }} - {{ item.0.key }}"
    loop: "{{ ip_interface_map | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"

gives (abridged) the same result
  msg: 10.0.0.10 - br0
  msg: 10.0.0.11 - br0
  msg: 10.100.0.10 - lxcbr0



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    interface_ips:
      br0:
        ipv4: [10.0.0.10, 10.0.0.11]
        ipv6: []
        mac: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
        mtu: '1500'
        type: bridge
      lxcbr0:
        ipv4: [10.100.0.10]
        ipv6: []
        mac: ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa
        mtu: '1500'
        type: bridge

    ip_interface_map: "{{ dict(interface_ips | dict2items |
                               json_query('[].[key,
                                              [value.ipv4, value.ipv6]|[]]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }} - {{ item.0.key }}"
      loop: "{{ interface_ips | dict2items | subelements('value.ipv4') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }} - {{ item.0.key }}"
      loop: "{{ interface_ips | dict2items | subelements('value.ipv6') }}"

    - debug:
        var: ip_interface_map

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }} - {{ item.0.key }}"
      loop: "{{ ip_interface_map | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"



This looks very elegant! I'll try it out later tomorrow.

You can probably iterate over your dictionary with a for loop, extracting all the sub-dictionary names (br0, lxcbr0 ...), then access the values under the key "ipv4". Something like that is a good start
for i,j in enumerate(interface_ips.keys()):
    # print(i,j)
    print(interface_ips[j]['ipv4'],'-',j)

then, rather than printing directly the ip you can of course store them in an array, append all the ip to the same array or in sub arrays and print it later and do whatever you want. For instance to provide an example of result as a list (as requested)
for i,j in enumerate(interface_ips.keys()):
    for k,l in enumerate(interface_ips[j]['ipv4']):
        print(l,'-',j)

would give
10.0.0.10 - br0
10.0.0.11 - br0
10.100.0.10 - lxcbr0

